# Cannot type in UITextfield

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have several `UITextfields` in one of my app's `Viewcontroller`. It works fine and I can type letters on those textfields. But sometimes cursor appears on the `UITextfield` but cannot type any letter on that. This does not happen always. What I do is when this problem occurs I delete that particular `UITextfield` and re-add a new `UITextfield`. But after performing several functionalities again that also gets the same problem.

What is the reason for this? And how to solve this problem. Please please help me. I'm fighting with this for several days.
Those are in Editable and User interactions are already enabled for these.

These are the delegates which I used

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];


if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==480) {

        if (textField.tag==7) {

            CGPoint npoint=originalCenter;
            npoint.y=180;
            self.view.center=npoint;
        }
        else if (textField.tag==8)
        {
            CGPoint npoint=originalCenter;
            npoint.y=125;
            self.view.center=npoint;
        }
        else{
            self.view.center=originalCenter;
        }
}

else{

    if (textField.tag==8)
    {
        CGPoint npoint=originalCenter;
        npoint.y=250;
        self.view.center=npoint;
    }
    else{
        self.view.center=originalCenter;
    }

}

[UIView commitAnimations];

}




- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];


self.view.center=originalCenter;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[textField resignFirstResponder];

return NO;

}



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range    replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if ([textField isEqual:txtPhonenumber]) {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 9) ? NO : YES;
}

else if ([textField isEqual:txtVerification])
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 4) ? NO : YES;
 }

}
```

Comment: First put code of creation of UITextField..

Comment: I just added as outlets. I didnt create them programmatically

Comment: Do you implement any of the delegate methods for UITextField ?

Comment: check your connections in the xib are correct

Comment: For the keyboard return key I have implemented to dissmiss that

Comment: Code will be much helpful of how you handle these text fields. Just using them as is shouldn't cause you any problems.

Comment: yes It works for some period. Suddenly this issue occurs. I delete that one and re add new textfield it works. But only for certain time period

Comment: Ok what are the functionalities are you doing, did it affect your textfield??

Comment: I updated the code. Can u plz check

Comment: When i check your code i saw you change the center of view for some UITextField and other are unchanged, check whether the your unresponsive textfields belongs to  changed view.

Comment: yes,those are belongs,, but not belonged textfields also give this sometimes. I have 4 UITextfields in one Viewcontroller. Change view applyed only for bottom 2 text fields. But sometimes middle UITextFields also give this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say without looking at implementation, but it may be due to your code in some of `UITextField` delegate methods especially -

1. if you return NO in –  `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` or
2. did something in wrong `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString`

Comment: Please post  – textFieldShouldBeginEditing: and textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString methods.

Comment: I havent Implemented textfieldshouldbegingediting only didbeginediting I will update the characters in range method

Comment: But this range method has not any deal with this particular textboxes

Comment: Please check if you have set textField delegate correctly and this method is not getting called for these textFields.

Comment: What should I imlement in textFieldShouldBeginEditing method?

Comment: return YES, if you implemented it. It will enable editing of textField.

Comment: I think In Range method I havent implemented else part it only has if and else if. I think by returning yes will slove the problem  else
        
        return YES;